# What does 7P mean?

Tags: guitar, notation

I'm trying to learn the song Ladye Nothynges Toye Puffe by John Renbourn and noticed the following symbol in the book (7P followed by a line). [image]

I have tried googling but didn't find anything. Thank you very much for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this means to play in 7th position: so that the first (index) finger plays on the 7th fret during the part below the horizontal line. In particular the last two notes should be played with barré on the 7th fret.

This is a fingering suggestion, you may follow it or not, depending on what feels better to you.

Comment: What does the P mean? Does it stand for something?

Comment: I suggest this is close to the mark but not quite spot on. I think it means play in the seventh position, not necessarily with a barre (but in this case a barre makes sense for the last two notes). If I’m correct, this notation has fallen out of favor and the current practice for indicating position on the guitar is with capital Roman numerals. I suspect the “p” stands for “position”.

Comment: @ToddWilcox right this makes sense, thanks! Going to update the answer.