# What do (P5) and (P6) mean? (Guitar)

Tags: guitar, notation, classical-music

Nocturne (Noturno) Op.9, No. 2 by Chopin. Tarrega's version, revised by Edson Lopes.

[image]In bars 18 and 19. P(5) and P(6) are written below the music. They are repeated throughout the piece with the same numbers.

Here is a link to the pdf. It's publicly posted by Lopes on his youtube channel.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Zb-iQH7ZRxQTf42jWcStdniZqswuRRdh/view

Comment: What piece is it?

Comment: What piece of music is this?

Comment: The piece is Nocturne (Noturno) Op.9, No. 2 by Chopin. Tarrega's version and revised by Edson Lopes.

Comment: Related question?: [What does 7P mean?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/106784/what-does-7p-mean/106785#106785)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess is that this is a reminder to mute the 6th or 5th string that would otherwise clash with the following chord. Guitarists often allow the low notes to sound, and note lengths are not always precisely marked in guitar scores.

E.g. measure 18 starts with Am chord with A in bass voice on the 5th string, followed by E chord with E on the 6th string. Note A would badly clash with chord E, so the A string should be muted at the time when you play E (or immediately after). Normally this is something a musician should realize on their own, it's also implied by the note length, and the "P5" mark is an extra reminder.

I noticed there is P6 mark in the first measure of the linked score, and in this recording of Edson Lopes

he doesn't mute the low E when the D# comes on the fourth beat. Perhaps this is something that he intended include in the arrangement, but later, when performing and guided by ears he didn't find the two notes clashing and "forgot" about muting. E-D# add up to a beautifully sounding Emaj7 there. I believe in the original E in bass moves downwards to D#, but when arranging for guitar he made a compromise by jumping by a seventh upwards. By allowing the two notes to sound together he undermines linearity of voice, but it is already undermined by inversion of the interval and a large jump, so maybe he made an arbitrary choice of what he likes better? These are the typical dilemmas of an arranger.  I guess you could try to play it both ways and see which way do you prefer.

In measure 5 (starting at 0:31 in the recording), when the melody is repeated with added ornamentation, you can clearly see him muting low E string with right thumb right after playing D#.

Comment: I think you’re right. The (P) always comes with the number of the string of the previous bass note. Now it seems so obvious especially at the part starting from bar 29. Thanks a lot!

Comment: So what would 'P' stand for? Pulgar?

Comment: @Tim Perhaps! I don't recall seeing this symbol before.

Comment: Reached the same conclusion when I first encountered scores frorm Edson Lopes. I assume the P stands for Pulgar indeed.

Comment: Still doesn't make a lot of sense: You'd use thumb to play the open E, but it says P5. Followed by P6 where there's nothing on the 6th string. As in how to mute 5th string open with thumb, while playing 6th string open. Rest stroke, maybe?

Comment: @Tim Check out the video at 0:36 when he plays the D# on the fifth string. He plays it first then places his thumb on the sixth string to stop it.

Comment: @Tim: I interpret it as the string that the thumb comes to rest on (and in effect dampening it). So in the case of the P5 in the image, a thumb rest stroke.

Comment: That is not the standard notation for a string.  Usually the string is a number in a circle.  The uncircled ones are fret numbers.  I'd be inclined to think position but the C7, etc, on top are position indicators.  P does usually mean thumb (pulgar) and is used for right hand fingering.  I've seen it in many books and scores along with i, m, a.  But not in parenthesis.

Comment: @ggcg I agree, this is not a standard notation for guitar. Perhaps arranging piano composition for guitar requires a nonstandard notation as well. I can imagine muting notation could be very useful, especially in pedagogical materials.

Answer (score 1):

This is just to confirm something already mentioned above. This kind of music notation, AFAIK, comes from Edson Lopes. In fact, in one of his (free) scores, Daily Technique, this is his very own note on (P6) "apoiar o polegar sobre a 6 corda", meaning "rest your thumb on the 6th string".

Source: http://tinyurl.com/TecnicaDiaria